# calculo de media em programação c

Tags: c, array, algoritmo

Olá

estou montando um código para uma atividade do meu curso porém a media que precisa aparecer no final caso seja digitado um numero negativo só aparece zero, sou iniciante em programação então não estou tendo a noção de oque pode estar errado no código, se alguém puder me dar uma orientação de oque pode ser feito para corrigir este problema ajudaria bastante.

obrigado

```
#include<stdio.h>


#include<stdlib.h>

int main() 

{

int c, cont, i, numero = 0, conta = 0;
float vetor[1000], media = 0, soma = 0;


cont = 0;
printf("Digite um numero:");
scanf_s("%d", &numero);
printf("\n");

while ((cont < 1000) && (numero >= 0))
{
    vetor[cont] = numero;

    printf("Digite um numero:");
    scanf_s("%d", &numero);
    cont++;
    printf("\n");
}
if (numero < 0)
{
    soma = cont++ + numero;
    conta = soma / numero;
    media = conta - numero <= 0;

}
printf("\n");
printf("A media dos numeros digitados e %d\n", &media);
printf("\n");




system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdlib.h>
  #define tamanho 10 //PARA MUDAR O TAMANHO DO VETOR BASTA ALTERAR O NÚMERO 
                                                            DESSA CONSTANTE.

  int main()
  {
    int  cont = 0, cont2=0, numero = 0;
    float  media = 0, soma = 0, vetor[tamanho];

    //Inicializando o vetor(Limpando o lixo de memória)

   for (int i=0; i<tamanho;i++)
  {
    vetor[i]=0.0;
  }
   do
  {
     printf("Digite um numero:");
     scanf("%d", &numero);
     printf("\n");

    if (numero >=0)
  {
    cont++; //CONTADOR PARA CALCULAR A MÉDIA

   vetor[cont2] = numero; //ARMAZENAMENRO DOS NÚMEROS NO VETOR
   soma += vetor[cont2]; //CALCULO DA SOMA TOTAL DOS NÚMEROS POSITIVOS
   cont2++; // INDÍCE DO VETOR.
  }

  }while (numero >= 0 && cont < tamanho);

  media = soma / cont; //CALCULO DA MÉDIA FINAL


  printf("\n");
  printf("A media dos numeros digitados e %.2f\n", media);
  printf("\n");




  system("pause");





  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: esse código que você me passou deu certo, testei aqui.. mas esse que vc me passou conta como um vetor de dados? vi que você não usou nada de vetor para montar o código..

Comment: Não precisa de vetor. Mas porque você estava utilizando um vetor?

Comment: esse código é para uma atividade que eu estou fazendo, e no enunciado pedia para eu digitar valores positivos e salvar os valores em vetores de dados. Por isso perguntei sobre.

Comment: Assim, entendo. E que você não deixou claro que precisava armazenar em um vetor os números. Caso ninguém comentar o código, com o vetor que você precisar eu edito o post, até amanhã a tarde, blz.

Comment: é eu esqueci de especificar, vou ir tentando aqui, se não conseguir entro aqui no post de novo para ver se alguém tem uma solução para me auxiliar.

Comment: Fiz a modificação, se era isso que você precisava, sinalize o meu post como a resposta para a dua dúvida por gentileza. Obrigado.

Comment: deu certo.. vlw pela orientação, me ajudou bastante..

Answer (score 0):

O cálculo da média não é uma questão de programação, mas sim uma questão de matemática. Como se calcula a média de n números ? Você soma os n números, e o resultado da soma você divide por n.

Traduzindo isto para C fica:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() 
{
  // contador de numeros digitados
  int n = 0;

  // acumulador dos numeros digitados
  double soma = 0;

  // media que sera' calculada
  double media;

  // numeros que serao digitados, um por vez
  double numero;

  // loop de leitura dos numeros digitados
  for (;;)
  {
    printf("Digite um numero:");

    // le um numero digitado
    scanf("%lf", &numero);

    // se leu um numero negativo entao sai do loop
    if (numero < 0)
      break;

    // incrementa contador de numeros lidos
    n++;

    // atualiza acumulador de numeros lidos
    soma += numero;
  } // for

  // consome ultimo enter
  getchar();

  if (n == 0)
  {
    printf("nao foi digitado nenhum numero\n");
  }
  else
  {
    media = soma / n;
    printf("A media dos numeros digitados e %lf\n", media);
  }

  printf("tecle ENTER para terminar");
  getchar();
}
```

Teste:

```
[~/Projects/testes/so]
$cc -o 377544 377544.c

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./377544
Digite um numero:123
Digite um numero:456
Digite um numero:789
Digite um numero:-1
A media dos numeros digitados e 456.000000
tecle ENTER para terminar

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$./377544
Digite um numero:-1
nao foi digitado nenhum numero
tecle ENTER para terminar

[~/Projects/testes/so]
$
```